# How on Earth can this variable change without any commands?

Tags: variables, printf

[image]

As you can see, the value of buffer[0] changes when the line `sprintf(tittle, %03d.jpg", images);`,  which has nothing to do with the buffer. All of the values in buffer are changed. I went through my code a thousand times, and I finally found out this. It's really frustrating! Any explanations?

Comment: Welcome to the world of memory corruption. Maybe you are using a free'd pointer or a pointer to a stack variable of a function that has already returned.

Comment: **Screenshot of text?** Seriously? Just no.

Comment: @user3477950 This is gdb, the GNU Debugger, not a plain text

Comment: @gexicide Could you, please explain a little further or give me the link to some explanation. buffer is a global array.

Comment: @DusanMilosevic and? that's entirely irrelevant. or is there no Copy-Paste on your OS?

Comment: @user3477950 It's an output of a program.

Comment: @DusanMilosevic: and you cannot copy the content of the output window ?

Comment: As you can see, it's in virtualbox. It's a bit complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allocate 4 chars for `title` but you try to write 8 chars (including the null terminator) into it. That doesn't fit, and C allows you to metaphorically shoot yourself in the foot. On most if not all systems it clobbers whatever happens to be next in memory, and in your case that's apparently the beginning of `buffer`.

Comment: Of course! How can I be so stupid! Thanks!